# How can exception have a NullReferenceException

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, exception

My code updates & inserts into a bunch of tables. About 2 months ago I got the same error as the one below, I assumed it was because the exception it self is `Nothing`.

So I built in a test to check if it isn't nothing, write the exception details.

However, the error in the screenshot occurred again this morning. My question now is how does a code block like the one below result in the Exception being `Null`, and in which cases will an exception be `Null`?

**Edited** - This is different to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) because I want to know how an EXCEPTION can be `Null`/`Nothing`

```
        Try
            If t.DpaPosted = "N" Then
                i += 1
                OutputCount += 1
                Dim SubAccountID As Integer = 0

                If t.SubaccountId = 0 Then
                    SubAccountID = GetSubAccountID(t.DpaInId)

                    If SubAccountID = 0 Then
                        If DupAcc > 1 Then
                            UpdateLog(t.clientReference & " - Multiple CLOSED(Paid Up/Refunds outstanding) accounts.")
                        Else
                            SubAccountID = GetClosedSubAccountID(t.DpaInID)

                            If SubAccountID = 0 Then
                                UpdateLog(t.clientReference & " - No accounts found.")
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If

                If SubAccountID <> 0 Then
                    If t.DpaDocNo <> "0" Then
                        If q.Execquery("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Transactions WHERE SubAccountID = " & t.SubaccountId & " AND TranTypeID = 6 AND TranAmount = " & t.DpaAmount & " AND DPANo = '" & t.DpaDocNo & "'") > 0 Then
                            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Sequence [" & t.DpaDocNo & "] already posted.<br/>")
                            dpaadapter.SetDpaPosted(t.DpaInId)
                        Else
                            PostDpa(SubAccountID, 6, t.DpaAmount, t.Dpadate, "0", t.DpaDocNo)
                            dpaadapter.SetDpaPosted(t.DpaInId)
                        End If
                    Else
                        PostDpa(SubAccountID, 6, t.DpaAmount, t.Dpadate, "0", t.DpaDocNo)
                        dpaadapter.SetDpaPosted(t.DpaInId)
                    End If
                End If

                If WriteOutput Then HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Imported [" + i.ToString + "] of [" + dpa.Rows.Count.ToString + "]<br/>")

                If OutputCount = 10 Then
                    OutputCount = 0

                    If WriteOutput Then
                        If HttpContext.Current.Response.IsClientConnected Then
                            HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush()
                            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script>window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);</script>")
                            HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush()
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Dim LogStr As String = ""
            LogStr = "Record [" & i.ToString & "]. "
            LogStr = "Ref [" & t.clientReference & "] - "

            If ex.Message.ToString <> Nothing Then LogStr = LogStr & ex.Message.ToString Else LogStr = LogStr & "No Exception Message"
            If ex.InnerException.ToString <> Nothing Then LogStr = LogStr & vbCrLf & ex.InnerException.ToString Else LogStr = LogStr & "No Inner Exception"

            UpdateLog(LogStr)
            SaveLog()
        End Try
```

I can't actually see what code is triggering the exception, until I can fix the exception handling.

**Some more information that might help**

1. I am using asp.net V 4.0
2. The code is in a class, and the file is located in the `appcode` directory.
3. The issue doesn't always trigger
4. When running the code for a second/third time, the exception doesn't trigger again. So I can't recreate the error all the time.
5. Windows event viewer didn't log any exceptions for this page.

**ANSWER**

Found from [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22826428/1396435)

> An inner exception is the exception that caused the current exception.
>
> It is used in cases when you want to surface a different exception
>   than the one that your code caught but you don't want to throw away
>   the original context.
>
> In order for a new exception to have information about a previous one,
>   like you said, you pass it as constructor parameter to the new one.
>
> Usually, a null inner exception means that the current exception is
>   root cause of the exceptional situation.

[image: Exception Example]

Comment: I would expect that the issue is here: `If ex.InnerException.ToString <> Nothing`. Why do you have that `ToString` call in there?  It serves no useful purpose and, if there is no inner exception, will throw a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I also found that that would be what is causing the exception, but `InnerException` is not supposed to be `Nothing`, the same can be said for `ex.Message` which also throws a `NullReferenceException` sometimes. That's why I am wondering why the `Exception` has nothing in the fields?

Comment: `This is different to this question because...` no it´s not. The way locating and fixing a NRE is always the same, thus your question is a dup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about safeguarding your ex.InnerException? Once you make sure that an InnerException exists then you can access its methods and properties.

```
If ex.InnerException Is Not Nothing AndAlso ... Then
```

See [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22826428/1465748) (and read the accepted answer) about `InnerException`. It is not necessary to have an InnerException, unless the current exception was caused by another exception.

Comment: The problem with `If ex.InnerException <> Nothing` code is the system then throws the error `Operator '<>' is not defined for types 'System.Exception' and 'System.Exception'.`

Comment: Forgive me, it's been some time since I last worked with vb.net, try `Is Not Nothing`. Also see my updated answer for the other part of your question.

Comment: Your right. Bases on this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/22826428/1396435 - `Usually, a null inner exception means that the current exception is root cause of the exceptional situation.`