# De-/serialization with a list of objects

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization

I try to save and read multiple objects in one XML-File.

The function Serialize is not working with my existing List, but i dont know why. I already tried to compile it but i get an error wich says, that the methode needs an object refference.

Program.cs:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Cocktail> lstCocktails = new List<Cocktail>();
            listCocktails.AddRange(new Cocktail[]
            {
                new Cocktail(1,"Test",true,true,
                new Cocktail(1, "Test4", true, true, 0)
        });


            Serialize(lstCocktails);

        }

        public void Serialize(List<Cocktail> list)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Cocktail>));
            using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\MapSample\bin\Debug\ListCocktail.xml"))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, list);
            }
        }

        private void DiserializeFunc()
        {
            var myDeserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Cocktail>));
            using (var myFileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\MapSample\bin\Debug\ListCocktail.xml", FileMode.Open))
            {
                ListCocktails = (List<Cocktail>)myDeserializer.Deserialize(myFileStream);
            }
        }
```

Cocktail.cs:

```
    [Serializable()]
    [XmlRoot("locations")]
    public class Cocktail
    {

        [XmlElement("id")]
        public int CocktailID { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("name")]
        public string CocktailName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("alc")]
        public bool alcohol { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("visible")]
        public bool is_visible { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("counter")]
        public int counter { get; set; }
        private XmlSerializer ser;

        public Cocktail() {
            ser = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType());
        }
        public Cocktail(int id, string name, bool alc,bool vis,int count)
        {
            this.CocktailID = id;
            this.CocktailName = name;
            this.alcohol = alc;
            this.is_visible = vis;
            this.counter = count;
        }
    }
}
```

Ii also think I messed something up with the DiserializeFunc().

Comment: it would help if you could post the serialization error you get. It would also be wise to try and make sense of the error by analyzing [inner errors in a try catch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22826067/what-is-inner-exception). You can also try to follow [this tutorial on list serialization](https://www.dotnetperls.com/serialize-list)

Comment: Now what is the problem? You didn't mention in the post

Comment: Side note: please avoid text unrelated to the problem like "new here", "thank you", "I'm Bob the Third" (or any other signature). Instead make sure that code provided in the post follows [MCVE] guidelines and all necessary information like input/output/error message  present in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close to implementing the Cocktail class correctly, but I think you're confused about how to serialize Lists. Your implementation of a Cocktail object class is completely fine, just get rid of the list related functions.

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Serialization_Help
{
    [Serializable()]
    [XmlRoot("locations")]
    public class Cocktail
    {

        [XmlElement("id")]
        public int CocktailID { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("name")]
        public string CocktailName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("alc")]
        public bool alcohol { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("visible")]
        public bool is_visible { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("counter")]
        public int counter { get; set; }
        public Cocktail() {

        }
        public Cocktail(int id, string name, bool alc, bool vis, int count)
        {
            this.CocktailID = id;
            this.CocktailName = name;
            this.alcohol = alc;
            this.is_visible = vis;
            this.counter = count;
        }
    }
}
```

Now in your new function you want to serialize the list directly.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Serialization_Help
{
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            List<Cocktail> list = new List<Cocktail> {
                new Cocktail(01, "rum and coke", true, true, 5),
                new Cocktail(02, "water on the rocks", false, true, 3)
            };
            Serialize(list);
            List<Cocktail> deserialized = DiserializeFunc();
        }

        public static void Serialize(List<Cocktail> list) {

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Cocktail>));
            using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\ListCocktail.xml")) serializer.Serialize(writer, list);
        }

        private static List<Cocktail> DiserializeFunc() {
            var myDeserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Cocktail>));
            using (var myFileStream = new FileStream(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\ListCocktail.xml", FileMode.Open)) return (List<Cocktail>)myDeserializer.Deserialize(myFileStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Doing so should correctly print out the following .xml output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfCocktail xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Cocktail>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>rum and coke</name>
    <alc>true</alc>
    <visible>true</visible>
    <counter>5</counter>
  </Cocktail>
  <Cocktail>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>water on the rocks</name>
    <alc>false</alc>
    <visible>true</visible>
    <counter>3</counter>
  </Cocktail>
</ArrayOfCocktail>
```

Keep in mind that I have not provided implementation of any of the standard safety or null checks for the file. You'll have to check if the file exists yourself by using `File.Exists(...)` [(see here for File.Exists implementation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385251/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-in-a-folder/35613558#35613558) and implement the correct `try` and `catch` cases and what your code will chose to do if it runs into serialization or input/outut errors.

Comment: Wow thank you for the great answer! This will help me as base for my program! If its ready to use u will get a Cocktail ;) :D

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use [ExtendedXmlSerializer](https://github.com/wojtpl2/ExtendedXmlSerializer) to serialize and deserialize.

**Instalation**
You can install ExtendedXmlSerializer from [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExtendedXmlSerializer/) or run the following command:

```
Install-Package ExtendedXmlSerializer
```

**Serialization:**

```
ExtendedXmlSerializer serializer = new ExtendedXmlSerializer();
var list = new List<Cocktail>();
var xml = serializer.Serialize(list);
```

**Deserialization**

```
var list = serializer.Deserialize<List<Cocktail>>(xml);
```

**Standard XML Serializer in .NET is very limited.**

- Does not support serialization of class with circular reference or class with interface property,
- Does not support Dictionaries,
- There is no mechanism for reading the old version of XML,
- If you want create custom serializer, your class must inherit from IXmlSerializable. This means that your class will not be a POCO class,
- Does not support IoC.

**ExtendedXmlSerializer can do this and much more.**

ExtendedXmlSerializer support **.NET 4.5** or higher and **.NET Core**. You can integrate it with WebApi and AspCore.