# OpenCVSharp: Unable to load DLL 'OpenCvSharpExtern'

Tags: c#, .net, opencv

I have installed the latest OpenCVSharp 2 (2.4.10.201...) with the NuGet manager in my project. Everything concerning OpenCVSharp.CvMat is working OK (loading, manipulation etc) so I am sure the installation is correct.

However I cannot use OpenCVSharp.CPlusPlus at all! **The problem is that it doesn't load OpenCvSharpExtern.dll.**

Error shown from try-catch block:

```
try
{
    Mat mat = new Mat();
} catch (Exception err)
{
    Console.WriteLine( err );
}

System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'OpenCvSharp.CPlusPlus.Mat' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'OpenCvSharpExtern': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at OpenCvSharp.CPlusPlus.NativeMethods.core_Mat_sizeof()
   at OpenCvSharp.CPlusPlus.Mat..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at OpenCvSharp.CPlusPlus.Mat..ctor()
   at MainClass.Main() in C:\Users\kotsias\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MyCVSharp\ConsoleApplication1\Test.cs:line 14
```

The **OpenCvSharpExtern.dll** ***IS*** deployed alongside my .exe inside the following subfolders:

**..\dll\x86**

&

**..\dll\x64**

If I manually copy the **x64 .dll** in the same folder as my .exe, I still get the same error above. If I copy the **x86 .dll**, I get a different error:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'OpenCvSharp.CPlusPlus.Mat' threw an exception. ---> System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
   at OpenCvSharp.CPlusPlus.NativeMethods.core_Mat_sizeof()
   at OpenCvSharp.CPlusPlus.Mat..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at OpenCvSharp.CPlusPlus.Mat..ctor()
   at MainClass.Main() in C:\Users\kotsias\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MyCVSharp\ConsoleApplication1\Test.cs:line 14
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having this problem in production (After Creating the Setup File and Installing it). I've solved it by doing the following steps

1. Installed the OpenCVSharp Through NuGet Packages
2. Setting the Platform Target to X64 in Project Properties
3. Creating the Setup File with the same Platform
4. Manually Copying the "packages\OpenCvSharp4.runtime.win.4.5.3.20210817\runtimes\win-x64\native\OpenCvSharpExtern.dll" file into the installation directory.

Answer (score 25):

It is not enough installing the "OpencvSharp{version} nuget" package.
You also have to install the "OpencvSharp{version}.runtime.{operating_system}" package.

For example, in my case I had to install the following Nuget pacages:

- OpencvSharp4
- OpencvSharp4.runtime.win

Comment: Installing `OpenCVSharp4.runtime.*` solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 5):

Another issue that some may be hitting:

OpenCvSharpExtern.dll requires mfplat.dll that is part of the Media Feature Pack. Windows 'N' editions do not include this by default.

It can be installed from Apps and Features->Optional features->Add a feature.

Comment: Also, on Server Core I fixed this with `Install-WindowsFeature -Name Server-Media-Foundation`

Comment: This answer probably saved a few hours of my life.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you don't have correct version of Visual C++ Redistributable package installed.

OpenCvSharp 2.4.10 uses Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable Package. However, [OpenCvSharp 2.4.10](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp_2410) is deprecated and author recommends to use [OpenCvSharp 3.2](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp):

> #OpenCvSharp 2.4.10 Cross platform wrapper of OpenCV 2.4.10 for .NET Framework.
>
> **This project is deprecated. The latest release is available in [OpenCvSharp](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp).**

For more information check:

- [Unable to load DLL (Module could not be found HRESULT: 0x8007007E)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003072/unable-to-load-dll-module-could-not-be-found-hresult-0x8007007e) discussion
- [Why Are There So Many “Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributables” Installed on My PC?](https://www.howtogeek.com/256245/why-are-there-so-many-microsoft-visual-c-redistributables-installed-on-my-pc/) article
- [OpenCvSharp 3.2 NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenCvSharp3-AnyCPU/) page.

Comment: I need to use 3.5 framework, so I'm probably stuck with the older version. I tried the latest one but it wouldn't work with anything less than 4.0.

Comment: Project README.md states that .NET Framework 2.0 and newer is supported. I created corresponding [issue](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp/issues/352) on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code on Package manager :

```
Install-Package OpenCvSharp4.Windows -Version 4.0.0.20190108
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and i found i needed to move my project off the WSL filesystem onto the normal C: drive