# Opencvsharp from IplImage to Bitmap

Tags: c#, opencv, visual-studio-2013

I am using vs 2013 and I have a opencvsharp 2* from nuget I have these codes:

```
 public List<IplImage> text = new List<IplImage>();
 ...
 IplImage bit = text[0];
 picturebox.Image = text[0].ToBitmap();
```

But this lines not accepted :

`picturebox.Image = text[0].ToBitmap()`;

ToBitmap is never come 
Any helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [OpenCvSharp3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenCvSharp3-AnyCPU/), `Mat` instance and `OpenCvSharp.Extensions.BitmapConverter.ToBitmap()` extension method. OpenCvSharp2 project is obsolete.

Relevant quote from OpenCvSharp2 [README.md](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp_2410/blob/master/README.md):

> #OpenCvSharp 2.4.10 Cross platform wrapper of OpenCV 2.4.10 for .NET Framework.
>
> **This project is deprecated. The latest release is available in OpenCvSharp.**

See [OpenCV: IplImage versus Mat, which to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232022/opencv-iplimage-versus-mat-which-to-use) thread and [Mat - The Basic Image Container](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/d6d/tutorial_mat_the_basic_image_container.html) docs page.

Comment: Thank you but when I install opencvsharp3 from nuget  I have dll errors

Comment: Please check [OpenCVSharp: Unable to load DLL 'OpenCvSharpExtern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44105973/opencvsharp-unable-to-load-dll-opencvsharpextern) discussion and [OpenCvSharp3 requirements](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp#requirements). OpenCvSharp uses Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Package. Do you have it installed?

Comment: hm  unfortunaly I am using vs2013

Comment: You can install Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Package separately. OpenCvSharp3 requirements page has a link to it.

Comment: Hi @Lenoid Vasilyev I install opencvsharp3 succesfully and I rewrite my code for it But some codes is not work Can you control my code please Before opencvsharp3 my code has  good result butnow not good result because I cant compile 2 code lines

Comment: Were you able to successfully assign your image to a `picturebox.Image` property? If so, please accept this answer and ask another question about your current issue. You may want to check [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide.