# An error occurred while sending the request, post

Tags: c#, console, client, token, webapi

I wanna get Token width windows console from web API and there is my code and I occurred an error:

> An error occurred while sending  the request,

I use visual studio 2013, .Net FrameWork 4.5,

```
private static async Task<string> GetAccessToken()
    {
        string baseUrl = "http://my.strategy.maskan";
        string _ClientId = "abc";
        string _ClientSecret = "password123";
        string _Scope = "api1";

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ClientId", _ClientId));
            postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ClientSecret", _ClientSecret));
            postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Scope", _Scope));


            FormUrlEncodedContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
            try
            {
                response = await client.PostAsync("IDENTITYSERVER", content);
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            string jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return jsonString;
            
        }
    }
```

exception produce in `response = await client.PostAsync("IDENTITYSERVER", content);`.
how can I fix this exception from httpClient.PostAsync.

Comment: You need to provide more information. Inner exception in `HttpRequestException ex` would help as well as the `ex.StatusCode`

Comment: You need to look at the [InnerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22826067/what-is-inner-exception)

Comment: There's something else after *An error occurred while sending the request*: what is that? Connection closed by the remote endpoint? Post the complete exception. -- Where is this code run, what System?

Comment: I solved that problem, I was in wrong LAN Network from my organization.
So I Execute it in correct Domain Server.

Answer (score 0):

This Error occurred because of, I posted request in wrong Domain server in my organization.
I ping my Address server then find out that does not have any response to me, so I execute it to another client that has Access to this Domain name server and then I have response from server.

```
ping my.strategy.maskan
```

response from wrong host: `Ping request could not find host -----. please check the name and try again`

response from correct host: `reply from -.-.-.- bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=62`